# Separate one variable into many by group

Tags: r

To include state specific annual trends in my felm fixed effects estimation, I would like to create a separate variable for each state which has the value 1 for the first year, 2 for the second and so on, and which is 0 for all other states.
I managed to create a variable ("stateyear" in the example) that fulfils all these requirements, except that it is just one variable for all states together (see example). Is there a way to split this variable into many variables by group (state_geocode_id) and set each of them to 0 for all other states but the respective?

Simplified dataset:

```
d <- data.frame("100")
names(d) <- "state_geocode_id"
d$state_geocode_id <- as.character(d$state_geocode_id)
d <- rbind(d, "100", "100", "100", "101", "101", "101", "101", "102", "102", "102", "102")
d$municip <- c("1", "1", "2", "2", "3", "3", "4", "4", "5", "5", "6", "6")
d$year <- c("2000", "2001", "2000", "2001","2000", "2001", "2000", "2001", "2000", "2001", "2000", "2001")
```

Adding "stateyear" variable:

```
d$stateyear <- as.numeric(factor(d$year))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

```
library(tidyverse)

d %>% 
  group_by(state_geocode_id) %>% 
  #add a row counter and duplicate the state id
  mutate(row = row_number(), 
         state2 = state_geocode_id) %>% 
  #now spread by the duplicate state to get a column for each state
  spread(key = state2, value = row, fill = 0)

# A tibble: 12 x 6
# Groups:   state_geocode_id [4]
state_geocode_id year  `100` `101` `102` `103`
<chr>            <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 100              2000      1     0     0     0
2 100              2001      2     0     0     0
3 100              2002      3     0     0     0
4 101              2000      0     1     0     0
5 101              2001      0     2     0     0
6 101              2002      0     3     0     0
7 102              2000      0     0     1     0
8 102              2001      0     0     2     0
9 102              2002      0     0     3     0
10 103              2000      0     0     0     1
11 103              2001      0     0     0     2
12 103              2002      0     0     0     3
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick response, that's exactly what I was looking for. I slightly modified the example dataset for I actually have a substate level (municipality), but grouping by state_geocode_id, year makes the solution generic enough to account for that.